Excel Sum a range based on the values from a database and sum the column corresponding to it
I need help getting the formula for this
Sum the equivalent value of a range based on a predefined database
Example:
Rob1    Ann1    Dory1   Rob1    Ann2     Dory2  Total 180


Rob1     10
Ann1     20
Dory1    30
Rob2     40
Ann2     50
Dory2    60

Thank you

Can you show us a sample in Excel? Is the Data 'Rob1 10 Ann1 20 Dory1 30 Rob2 40 Ann2 50 Dory2 60' in one row or in 2 columns in Excel?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

First list in A1:A6, predefined database in C1:D6,
=SUM(XLOOKUP(A1:A6,C1:C6,D1:D6,0))




You understood the question perfectly well despite the lack of structure of my query. 2. The formula worked perfectly as well. I was trying to do it using Sumif to no avail. Thank you very much for your help. more power to you sir.


You're most welcome!

If your data is in columns, in separate cells, you can use a formula like this:
=SUM(SUMIF($C$3:$C$8, $A$3:$A$8, $D$3:$D$8))




You understood the word problem very well despite the lack of structure of my question. 2. The formula worked pretty well. It's very clever using sum with sumif I like it. Very smart simple equation. Thank you so much. More power to you sir.

